# Dropwizard nested transactions

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, dropwizard

I have method in my resources to creating users in bulk. 
I annotate my resource method with @UnitOfWork, but my specific service method for this operation are annotated too, because situation when only part of the users are saved is okey for me.

Summarazing I have main transaction, and many nested transactions needed to save users separately.

I noticed dropwizard can't begin transaction when my resource method is not annotated with @UnitOfWork and my service BulkSave method is. From logical point of view this should work but isn't working.

I tried to set flush mode using @UnitOfWork, first I set FlushMode to Manual, and this was almost perfect. When nested transaction is rollback, main transaction can be commit, this is great solution.
But this solution wasn't as good as I thought. Saving related entities using cascade don't work!

Finally I have related entities which aren't saved, or error in main transaction when nested transaction is rollback (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)

Anyone had similar situation or know more about Session management in Dropwizard?

Answer (score 2):

`@UnitOfWork` is only registered for Resource methods. So annotating your service methods wouldn't work.

Instead you in your Resource method set:

```
@UnitOfWork(transactional = false)
```

So that the entire method isn't wrapped up in a single transaction, but you still get the hibernate `Session` from `UnitOfWork`. Then in your DAO methods, control the transactions manually by:

```
   Transaction transaction = currentSession().beginTransaction();
   try {
       // do some transactions
       transaction.commit();
   } catch (Exception e) {
       transaction.rollback();
       throw new RuntimeException(e);
   }
```

Comment: This doesn't necessarily create a new transaction. `beginTransaction()` will return the active transaction if it's available. So it doesn't necessarily create a nested transaction;